# How can you move Azure Devops organisations to a different tenancy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We currently have an Azure organisation, containing several projects and related boards etc, linked to a specific Azure Active directory and tenant id.

Does anyone know if there is a way I can move the organisation and all child objects to a new tenancy/Azure Active directory?

We need to do this as we wish to decommission the original active directory.

I've googled for solutions and can see that other people were waiting for Microsoft to provide a solution.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the same using the following instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops

Trick here is not to use a Work or School Account.

Comment: Hi, when you moved your organisation to a new tenancy did all of the child items of the organisation (wiki, boards, pipelines test plans etc) all move across to the new tenancy or did you need to carry out any additional steps?

Comment: They all moved across for me.

Comment: @VenuraAthukorala what about the AD users that were added, do they move too?

Comment: That had to be done again!

Comment: while migration does assigned users or members get migrate to that tenant also