# Azure Dev-Ops - Change billing subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We have our azure services built like this :

### Company 1

1. Tenant 1
2. Subscription 1
3. Azure dev-opps 1 ( Projects, Builds, Release's, Source Control History )
4. Azure active directory 1 ( user@company1.com (same username as bellow) )

### Company 2

1. Tenant 2
2. Subscription 2
3. Azure services 2 ( Virtual Machines, VPN's, Database's, Apps, etc )
4. Office 365 2
5. Azure active directory 2 ( user@company2.com (same username as above) )

So, we want to delete Tenant 1 and migrate Azure dev-opps 1 to the tenant 2 and subscription 2, without losing the things we have there. ( Projects, Builds, Release's, Source Control History )

It is possible to change it like this and how can I do it? I'm admin in both.

Comment: Did you look into this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops? Trick is not to use a Work or School Account. A similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100615/how-can-you-move-azure-devops-organisations-to-a-different-tenancy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By doing this, can I also change the subscription Id?
Or what will happen to our devops, when we delete Organization 1/Tenant 1/SubscriptionId 1 from Azure?

Comment: Hi @CésarAfonso, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: We still didn't try to delete subscription 1 and tenant 1 but we move Azure DevOps to the other AD and we still weren't billed by MSFT. ( To understand if the bill goes for the subscription 1 bill or to the subscription 2 bill )
As far as Azure DevOps it seems Ok, 

My major concern is losing the projects/builds/release/history from Azure DevOps. 
I marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Allen Wu.

We need add the account user@company1.com to the Tenant2 and ensure that this account is a member of Project Collection Administrator in the Org Azure dev-opps 1.

Then we can change your organization connection to another Azure AD.

Steps: open org settings->Azure Active Directory
->click the button Switch directory and select a directory from the dropdown menu, then select Connect.

Please refer this link for more details: [Change your organization connection to another Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops)

Note: It will not lose the data you have there